# Angular.js app with login

Tags: rest, angularjs, web, authentication

I am front-end developer and i have a job to build front-end part of web app using angular.js. I am new to angular.js.

I want to build SPA (single page application) and I require few pointers how to start. App has a login screen and 2 screens with forms. I was given a protocol:

Login Protocol:

```
URI : /login
HTTP Operation : POST
Input JSON document : {"userid":"xxxxx", "password":"xxxxxx"}
Response Code : 200 (success), 401 (unauthorized), 500 (server error)
Response Document : { "token" : "dsfafafdaadfadfadfda" }
```

Server is a REST service, developed using Java running on tomcat server.

Comment: Hi Oshenko and welcome on Stackoverflow. This site is for getting answers on specific technical questions, not for general programming advice. Please reword your question. See also stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

start exploring https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app

this is a great demo app which explains how things works in AngularJs

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i did check it and I am doing great.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to angular I'd recommend starting with going through their tutorial at http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial.